# What is the shortest Spring Framework class name (package included)?

Tags: spring, naming

Many people have [found](https://twitter.com/ftrain/status/242597696949604352) [humor](https://twitter.com/NeckbeardHacker/status/244078549500301313) in the deprecation of `org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean`.

This led me to wonder: what is the *shortest* class name, including the package in the Spring Framework 3.1.x ecosystem (listed here: http://www.springsource.org/projects)?

Comment: Seems like this is essentially a one-liner to discover automatically, once you have target jars. (Well, 1-10 lines, depending on implementation. But short.)

Answer (score 20):

Eyeballing http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/ which is the main Spring Framework API, there are a few 4 letter words including `Bean`.

But I don't think that AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean is the longest class name in the Spring API.  Here are some competitors:

```
AbstractSingletonProxyFactoryBean
SmartInstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor 
SingletonMetadataAwareAspectInstanceFactory 
JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory
TransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy  
JdbcUpdateAffectedIncorrectNumberOfRowsException
```

Comment: And still, they are all dwarfed by [HasThisTypePatternTriedToSneakInSomeGenericOrParameterizedTypePatternMatchingStuffAnywhereVisitor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.aspectj/com.springsource.org.aspectj.weaver/1.6.3/org/aspectj/weaver/patterns/HasThisTypePatternTriedToSneakInSomeGenericOrParameterizedTypePatternMatchingStuffAnywhereVisitor.java)

Comment: as of Spring 5.3.14, this is the longest class name, coming in at 52 characters: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/RequestMappingInfoHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy.html